# jQuery - remove element on blur BUT catch click on his children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
$('#myEl').blur(function(){
  $(this).remove('.children');
});
```

But the children element have links inside, with another jQuery actions which doesn't trigger because the .children is removed on blur, which I guess is triggered before the click action. Simple example:

1. Children is visible and #myEl have focus
2. I click on the children link
3. #myEl loses his focus
4. Children element is removed
5. Children link action is not triggered, because I guess link is not present anymore

How to solve this? I was trying to delay remove:

```
$(this).delay(100).remove('.children');
```

With no luck.

Comment: strange to use `$(this).remove('.children');` ...selector argument of `remove()` is a filter

Comment: That is just an example. Remove function isn't the point here.

Comment: that's fine, still strange to see filter selector in it using `this` as main selector

Comment: Exact code looks: $(this).closest('div').find('.children').remove();

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with the *delay* way, you can't use jQuery `.delay()` since it only work on queued element (with animation).

You can use `setTimeout` :

```
$('#myEl').blur(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    $this.remove('.children');
  }, 100)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it with mousedown event and it worked fine. I don't thing adding a delay is always a good option.

```
   <input type="text" id="myEl"></input>
    <div class="children" >div child</div>
    <script>
        $('#myEl').blur(function(e){
            $('.children').remove();

        });

        $(".children").mousedown(function() {
            window.open('http://www.google.com')
        });
    </script>
```

And if you really want to add the click event for a specific reason then you can try this:-

```
       $('#myEl').blur(function(e){
            if(mousedown){
               window.open('http://www.google.com'); 
               mousedown = false;
            }
            $('.children').remove();

        });
        $('.children').click(function(e){
            window.open('http://www.google.com')
        });
        $(".children").mousedown(function() {
           mousedown = true
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

what about simply making the child elements hidden after a click? Or maybe even having the child itself remove all children from its parent container after it has processed the click?

`$('#myEl').blur(function(){
  $(this).children('.children').hide();
});
$('.children').on("click",function(){
  // perform your click-code actions here
  alert("I did it!");
  // now remove your child elements from the parent
  $(this).parent().children('.children').remove();
});`